# Add two density curves (from separate tables) into same plot (using ggplot in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two tables mresm, mresf with a numeric column Total in both tables (different values). Plotting a density plot for either of the two in R can be done in the following way:

> mresm %>% ggplot(aes(x = mresm$Total)) + geom_density()
> mresf %>%  ggplot(aes(x = mresf$Total)) + geom_density()

However, I want to add both the resulting curves on the same plot to be able to compare them. Have tried a lot of alternatives with no success. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify inside `geom_density` the `data` and `aes` arguments:

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_density(data = mresm , aes(x = Total))+ 
      geom_density(data = mres ,  aes(x = Total))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like thins should work:

```
mresm = data.frame(name = rep("mresm", 10), Total = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
mresf= data.frame(name = rep("mresf", 10), Total = c(15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24))

df = rbind(mresm,mresf)
my_plot =  ggplot(df, aes(x = df$Total, fill=name)) + geom_density()
my_plot
```